# c# .net core 2.1 system environment variable console application not loading

Tags: .net, console-application, .net-core-2.1

I'm using c# .net core 2.1 CONSOLE application.  I can see the predefined system environment variables using:

```
configuration.GetValue<string>("TMP")
```

However, when I create a new system variable it is not visible to the application.

If I hover over configuration I see the JsonConfigurationProvider and the EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider, but the one's I created are not listed.

For instance I created a new system environment variable on my machine named Database.  I figure I could call is using configuration.GetValue("Database")

This is how I'm loading the configurations.

```
configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
```

Any sugguestions? Remember, I'm using a console application and not ASP.NET.

Comment: Did you restart the application after defining the variable?

Comment: where did you defined a variable? is it on appsettings.json or not ? the system environment is not the same as environment variable, these are two different things.

Comment: @SiavashGhanbari, when I hover the configuration object, it displays a list of system environment variables.  It just doesn't show the one I just created.  I can even modify an existing one and it works, but it will not show a newly created on, even after a system reboot.

Comment: I replied the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52667992/1404642 and let me know if you have other problem about this issue.

Comment: @omajid is correct. just need to restart visual studio after defining the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not change the `System Environment Variable`, you must change `Project Environment Variable` By right clicking the project and selecting Properties or by simply opening launchSettings.json, you will see the list of profiles:

```
{
  ...
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
         "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication14": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And don't forget to restart your application when you edited or added a variable.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  My goal is to move the database connection string into an environment variable and read it from there.  I don't want a user to have to deal with a .json file in PROD.  I see people using it, but all the examples stop at the .AddEnvironmentVariables().

I don't see any examples of how to add a new environment variable and then consume in in the console application.  Hope that helps understand my issue.

Comment: Right click on your Console application project and select properties then select Debug | and set Environment variable.

Comment: @Siavish, thanks.  I get it now.  So on the client machine they would have to add an environment variable there to match the name I create in the Debug section. Correct?

Comment: Is there no way to make the environment variable config provider read the config from the $#@!? environment variables?!?